# Compile error when importing bootstrap file into component

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap locally in an angular project and I am trying to reference the `_variables.scss` file inside a component. When I do that I get a compile error. Am I importing this wrong? If I do not import it, it compiles fine but it seems to have an issue when importing to another component

I have the bootstrap scss files locally downloaded in my styles folder. I have added the `includePath` for easier referencing

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "src/styles/"
  ]
},
```

and I import the file in my component scss file like so:

```
@import '_variables.scss';

.validator-item span {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

but when I go to compile I get the error:

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a fix? This is causing me issues too, whats weird is that this issue is still around, and very little info about it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not importing anything wrong, that's not the error message you are getting.

If you look at your error message, you are using an invalid CSS value when calling `$negative-spacers: negativify-map($spacers) !default;`

Your sass preprocessor cannot handle what you are trying to do, thus throwing the error during the compilation time.

Comment: This is just the default bootstrap variables file though.I have not done anything to it. It clearly compiles normally if I do not import it but it seems to have an issue when I do

Comment: You should probably add a `scss` tag to your question then. Folks over there are more likely to be able to help you.